# Mongoose: findOneAndUpdate does not update an existing field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to fetch every minute a web API data to MongoDB, save it and update when there is any change. The problem is the `volume`(every field) field is updated only (happens after a new trading day starts) when the new `date`  is added to `ChildSchemaData` - subdocumet. All this data is used to build a daily (NOT hourly/minute ) stock chart on front-end. And I am trying to stream it from database but since the `volume` (and all other fields in subdocument) is not updated in database nothing is changing on front-end. I am trying to implemet change Streams MongoDB (data stream from database) so I insist on getting data from database. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

**Edit1**: The `$addToSet` operator adds a value to an array unless the value is already present, in which case `$addToSet` does nothing to that array. It looks like that is the problem. I am wondering if there is a different operator that would update the value that is already present.

**Edit2**: I was playing around with the following syntax but not sure if it is correct

```
const update = {
      $addToSet: { data: webApiData },
      $set: { 'data[0].$.volume': webApiData[0].volume },
    };
```

because it is getting into the same `path` it is not going to work

**Controller**

```
const creatStock = async (symbol, webApiData) => {
  try {
    const query = { symbol };
    const update = { $addToSet: { data: webApiData } };
    const options = { upsert: true, new: true };

    await Stock.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options);
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(`creatStock error: ${ex}`.red);
  }
};
```

**Schema**

```
const ChildSchemaData = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: false,
  date: { type: mongoose.Types.Decimal128 },
  open: { type: mongoose.Types.Decimal128 },
  high: { type: mongoose.Types.Decimal128 },
  low: { type: mongoose.Types.Decimal128 },
  close: { type: mongoose.Types.Decimal128 },
  volume: { type: mongoose.Types.Decimal128 },
});

const ParentSchemaSymbol = new mongoose.Schema({
  symbol: {
    type: String,
  },
  // Array of subdocuments
  data: [ChildSchemaData],
});
```

Comment: So you want to update the same element in the child collection array? How do you determine which element to update?

Comment: I want to update whatever element is going to change. as an example if the volume is saved as 100 and then next time when webApi is fetched the same volume will be updated to 200 and so on. I hope I did not confuse you too much

Comment: I posted a solution to my question but the problem with that solution that it will update everything losing the old data and what I need is to append to the existing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution was provided by [srinivasy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7237613/srinivasy) at the following link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58984143/mongoose-how-to-update-an-existing-element-in-array)

```
const creatStock = async (symbol, webApiData) => {
  try {
    // reversed array
    const webApiDataReversed = webApiData.reverse();
    const query = { symbol };

    const position = await Stock.findOne(query);

    if (!position) {
      console.log('New stock'.green);
      return Stock.create({
        symbol,
        data: webApiDataReversed,
      });
    }

    await Stock.bulkWrite([
      {
        updateOne: {
          filter: query,
          update: { $pop: { data: 1 } },
        },
      },
      {
        updateOne: {
          filter: query,
          update: {
            $addToSet: {
              data: webApiDataReversed,
            },
          },
        },
      },
    ]);
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(`creatStock error: ${ex}`.red);
  }
};
```

Comment: Found a solution. Need to write up an answer explaining the process - will update in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update an element in an array, you can consider the [positional operator: $](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) and add the field to your update query.

This identifies an element in an array to update based on a condition.

Example to update the embedded array with a `volume` field equal to 100 and set to 200:

```
db.getCollection("collection").findOneAndUpdate({
    id: 1,
    "data.volume": 100
}, 
    { $set: { "data.$.volume": 200 } 
});
```

Comment: I guess it will work for the current day but then it comes to the next day and we need to append a new date to the array and update the volume for the current day till the trading ends at the end of the day

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible to this `const update = {
      $addToSet: { data: webApiData },
      $set: { 'data[0].$.volume': webApiData[0].volume },
    };`